# Why do i get a unrecognized option '--dynamic-linker' error while Building avin2/SensorKinect for android, NDK, gcc

Tags: android, c++, git, gcc, android-ndk

the makefiles i got from the git repo are looking like this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../Include/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../Source/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../Source/XnCommon \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../Source/External/LibJPEG \
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -fvisibility=hidden -DXN_FORMATS_EXPORTS
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--export-dynamic --dynamic-linker 
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := OpenNI libusb XnCore
LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS := libc 
LOCAL_MODULE := XnFormats
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok the pushed the makefiles with a little syntax error - it worked like this (no space,comma)

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--export-dynamic,--dynamic-linker
```